# Can I pass an error message from a C# executable out into a VBScript

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have a C# command executable I created.  In it, I have built some error handling.  I would like to be able to pass these thrown errors out of the program into another script that the users will have control over (in VBS).  I have seen I can set the `Environment.Exit` integer, but can I send my error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171222/can-i-pass-an-error-message-from-a-c-sharp-executable-out-into-a-vbscript#comment61877313_37171222) mentioned: write the error message to STDERR. If you run your executable via the [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method you can get the exit code and error message like this:

```vb
Set ex = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("C:\path\to\your.exe")

While ex.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

exitcode = ex.ExitCode
errormsg = ex.StdErr.ReadAll
```